Copy data across 2 Excel files
I'm a beginner level Excel user.
I have 10 Excel files with different division names like ABCD, ELFD, etc.
Their structure is as show in the picture:

Above excels are generated each quarter with Q1 actuals, Q2 actuals and so on as the quarters progress.
I want to copy the Q1 actuals, Q2 actuals etc. after every quarter against the correct Vote/Item in another excel which has below structure:

Currently, I filter by divisions ABCD, ELFD etc. and do it manually by matching Vote/Item.
What might be an efficient way to implement a better solution?
Thanks for your advice!

If you want to use Power-Query for this as the tags suggest - are the 10 files all in the same folder?  If so you can use Data > Get Data > From File > From Folder to grab data from all files in the same query.  In your source data image - is it just the top three that are allocated to ELFD and the data below the black line are allocated to Enrolment, Funding, etc.... or does the division identifier come from the file name?

thanks for your response.
The source screenshot is from ELFD excel wherein copy relevant vote-item and standard account from this file to the destination file's vote-item and standard account.
Division identifier doesnt exactly come from filename. rather we have 10 excels for those 10 divisions and presently we filter those divisions and do manual copy-paste
